# why my xampp server is not starting when i updated it

Tags: php, xampp

In order to update PHP I downloaded the latest version of XAMPP which is 3.2.3 and installed it in the `newxampp` directory and then I renamed it to `xampp` and the previously present xampp folder was renamed to `xamppp` or something. Now the current xampp has the latest PHP version which is php7 but when I run the Apache and MySQL, it does not start and give me the message

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.   
[Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,        
[Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.   
[Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check   
[Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues   
[Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this   
[Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: When I get a message like that I run command prompt as administrator and type `net stop http` followed by `Y`, if it works I know someone messed about with my port settings.

Comment: verify the httpd.conf! wrong configuration don't left the server start and verify the generated log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes in that bundled servers you have defined variables that set the path for the php module directory or some other parts. So you should rename the old directory first then install the new one to that directory that you have a running version and copy the needed parts back to the new one.

Otherwise i think you get some problems in running it.

Comment: yeah absolutely, i renamed it after installation. Now i uninstalled the xampp and deleted the previous directories and installed the fresh xampp again and its working now. Anyway, thanks alot.